# Power Query Calendar

Tags: calendar, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to create a calendar using Power Query functions and for that I used below syntax in blank query:

```
Source= Duration.TotalDays(DateTime.LocalNow() - #datetime(2014,01,01,00,00,00)) * 24
Date= List.DateTimes(#datetime(2014,01,01,00,00,00), Source ,#duration(0,1,0,0))
```

Then I convert to a table and apply query.
Connect dimension date table to date column in fact table.

The error occurs when I’m trying to mark table as date table:

> ‘The date column can only gave one timestamp per day. The date column
> can’t have gaps in dates’

What I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says:

> The date column can only have **one timestamp per day**.

While you are trying to add 24, one for each hour. See the [requirements for setting a table as a date table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-date-tables#setting-your-own-date-table):

> if it is a Date/Time data type, it has the **same timestamp across each value**

i.e. you can have only one value for each date, and if it is not a date, but datetime value, all time values should be the same.